Why does numpy.clip and numpy.ndarray.clip have different argument names?
The numpy.clip function goes
numpy.clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None, **kwargs)
The numpy.ndarray.clip method goes
ndarray.clip(min=None, max=None, out=None, **kwargs)
Is there a reason/consistency across numpy for one using a_min and a_max, and the other using min and max?
It seems it hasn't confused too many people before, the only issue I could find mentioning it is old and I'm not sure there's an answer there
For example
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[2,1],[-1,-2]])
np.clip(a, min=-1.5, max=1.5)

TypeError: clip() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a_min' and 'a_max'


The linked issue contains a guess:

... maybe this was done on purpose because the function is written in Python and could clash with the builtins min/max. The method is written in C and therefore doesn't have this issue.

Here is my additional guess:
The person who implemented this function probably used built-in min and max functions, so he decided to change the names of the arguments instead of applying the proper disambiguation mechanism. The names of the arguments have little significance to the user, because the function was not designed to be used with keyword arguments.

All np.clip does is
return _wrapfunc(a, 'clip', a_min, a_max, out=out, **kwargs)

More significant than the names is that one only accepts positional arguments.  The method accepts either.  The difference shouldn't be confusing to you as a user.
Answers to why questions can come from the docs, code comments, github didcussions, or guesses from users like us.

Thanks for the explanation and the "bigger picture". Both accept positional and keyword arguments, no?

As you found the min/max bounds can only be positional with the function. With the method they can be positional or keyword.  Both have other keyword arguments.  It's simplest to just read the docs, and not  worry too much about patterns or consistency.
